# Attempted import error: 'createGlobalStyle' is not exported from 'styled-components'

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui, styled-components

I am try to import createGlobalStyle from styled-components but it does not seem to be working. I installed styled-components npm package, the version is @3.4.10.

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
html {
    height: 100%
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

`
export default GlobalStyle
```

The above code is where I am trying to import createGlobalStyle

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import GlobalStyle from './theme/globalStyles'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <GlobalStyle />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And this is the index.js file where I am using the GlobalStyle component.

After running the code I am getting the following error:

```
./src/theme/globalStyles.js
Attempted import error: 'createGlobalStyle' is not exported from 'styled-components'.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `styled-components` version `3.4.10`, then you have to use `injectGlobal` instead of `createGlobalStyle`, because `createGlobalStyle` was only release in v4 of `styled-components`. Check it out: [[Deprecated] injectGlobal](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#deprecated-injectglobal)

So, in order for your code to work, you have to change a few things:

```
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyle = injectGlobal`
html {
    height: 100%
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
`

export default GlobalStyle
```

And in your `index.ts`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import GlobalStyle from './theme/globalStyles'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <GlobalStyle /> // this comes first
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!!!, I am totally new to styled components, that's why I was confused.

Comment: @OybekToshmatov you're welcome. You should definitely update to the newer version, since this one has already some deprecated functionalities.